# jQuery .toggle() Modal show/hide dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've browsed some similar questions - but I've been looking forever and no luck finding an implementation that's the same as what I'm looking to do.

It's VERY simple:

```
<a class="contacttoggle" href="#">Contact</a>
<div>Lots of content between</div>
<div>Lots of content between</div>
<div>Lots of content between</div>
<div>Lots of content between</div>
<div class="contact_box">Contact info that is initially hidden and then fades in when the "contact_toggle" Contact link above is clicked</div>
```

I'm looking for this to fade in and it will be absolutely positioned on the page (no worries I can handle the CSS).  I just **DO NOT** want a slide effect.  Just fade in.

I feel like this code should work but it's not :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    /* function to show and hide main navigation conatct box */
    $(".contact_box").hide();

    $('a.contacttoggle').click(function() { 
        $(this).next("div").find(".contact_box").toggle(400);
        return false;
    }); 


})
```

Comment: `$(".contact").hide();` should be `$(".contact_box").hide();` right?   what does 'not work' mean?  the click does nothing?

Comment: You're right - it is correct in the code I'm working on - just edited the question... whoops!  But yeah, still not working.

Comment: what does 'not work' mean?  nothing happens when you click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)?

Comment: but that will go only in one direction (showing).  he wants it to toggle

Comment: @jon_darkstar well it's not that hard to get to [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) from there if he looks around.

Comment: good call.  BAM!  Got it, although @jon_darkstar was right, not sure if I would have found it, been looking for it a while :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather then `toggle()`, just [`animate()` opacity with 'toggle'](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/egy87/).

```
$(".contact_box").animate({opacity:'toggle'}, 400);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about blockUI? It's one of those Plugins I really overuse.

Go to this link for more information:
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(this).next("div").find(".contact_box").toggle(400);
```

Try

```
$("div.contact_box").toggle(400);
```

Comment: is there something im missing?  the first way seems needlessly complicated but i feel like its there for a reason